# Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong New to Python

Tags: python

My requirement is to look through a folder and combine only the csv files in it into one. The csv files are consistent but cannot be just concatenated. I am only interested in rows where the first element in the row is a date else I need to discard that row.

The code that I have made progress till now is below which as usual is not working:

```py
import os
import csv
from dateutil.parser import parse

def datecheck(string):
    try:
        parse(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        False


file_ext = "csv"
os.chdir ("C:\\BANK_PROJECT\\FILES\\RAW_SOURCE_FILES")

file_list = os.listdir("C:\\BANK_PROJECT\\FILES\\RAW_SOURCE_FILES")

with open("outfile.csv", "w") as outfile:
    print(file_list)
    for file in file_list:
        if file.__contains__(".csv"):
            with open(file, 'r') as infile:
                data = csv.reader(infile)
                for row in data:
                    if len(row) > 0:
                        if datecheck(row[0]):
                            outfilewriter = csv.writer(outfile)
                            outfilewriter.writerows(row)
                    else:
                        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
from glob import glob
from dateutil.parser import parse


def datecheck(string):
    try:
        parse(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        False


files = glob('*.csv')

with open('outfile.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for file in files:
        with open(file) as infile:
            reader = csv.reader(infile)
            data = [row for row in reader if datecheck(row[0])]
            writer.writerows(data)
```

Input file 1:

```
new,1,2,3
2012-01-19 17:21:0,1,2 ,3
2012-01-19,1,2,3
xx,2,3,4
```

Input File 2:

```
new,1,2,3
2012-03-19 17:21:0,1,2 ,3
yy,1,2,3
2012-04-19,1,2,3
xx,2,3,4
```

Output:

```
2012-01-19 17:21:0,1,2 ,3
2012-01-19,1,2,3
2012-03-19 17:21:0,1,2 ,3
2012-04-19,1,2,3
```

Comment: The above code writes each character in a separate cell instead of being coma delimited. Also each word gets written to a separate fline

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: This is the output file: 2012-01-19 17:21:0,1,2 ,3
2012-01-19,1,2,3
2012-03-19 17:21:0,1,2 ,3
2012-04-19,1,2,3

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Was  looking at the old file which was being generated through my code. :(